# How to display same columns item in two different table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two different table, called like **News** and **SpotNews**.. And these tables have two same column like **id ,News_Title and News_Content**.. The question about ; how can i display sql results in a same query ?

For example (output should be like this);

```
id      News_title      News_Content
====================================
23      Title abc       content 123     // Comes from News
67      Title ahs       content 233     // Comes from Spot_News
223     Title abc4      content 321     // Comes From Spot_News
367     Title ahseq     content tg3     // Comes from News
567     Title ahs2      content 2da     // Comes from News
```

Could you write a sql query for this ?
Thanks.

Comment: How would you know which data to show?  What's the criteria?

Comment: @Rocket i just want to display news title and news content column in these tables (they have same column)

Comment: So, there's no link between them?

Comment: have it. but i dont need that column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

```
SELECT id, news_title, news_content FROM table_one
UNION ALL
SELECT id, news_title, news_content FROM table_two
```

Comment: thank you very much ;) i just learn UNION with you (: Have great one.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `UNION` operator.

```
SELECT id, News_title, News_content FROM News WHERE 1 = 1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, News_title, News_content FROM Spot_News
```

`UNION` allows you to collate the results from two queries, provided that they have exactly the same number of fields. Each query can have its set of `WHERE` clauses, too!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just need to create multiple queries.

```
$query = "SELECT news from TABLE_ONE WHERE ...";
$query2 = "SELECT news from TABLE_ONE WHERE ...";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);

$allnews = $result.$result2;

$while($row=mysql_fetch_array($allnews)){echo "$row[anything you want to echo here]";}
```

I have not tested this code, so just try it.

Comment: you can't concat result with `.` operator